# SELECT from SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table which contains the names of a country, the population of the country and the countries GDP, how would I display the names of the country and their per capita GDP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL allows calculations to be performed inline, like:

```
SELECT Name, GDP / Population AS [Per Capita GDP] FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 12):

```
SELECT name, gdp/NullIf(population,0) AS PerCapitaGDP FROM "MyCountryTable"
```

Comment: In the unlikely case that GDP is integral (not a decimal or float) and you're interested in precision to fractional values, remember to cast one the values (probably GDP) to a decimal or float before dividing)

Comment: I would add a "where population > 0" to avoid any possibility of division by zero as well.

Comment: @ocdecio: good point, though that would be a weird situation... I doubt there are any countries with a 0 population, and if you don't know the population a reasonable schema would represent that with NULL, which wouldn't cause an error here.

Comment: @Joel - if a column *can* contain the value 0, it will sooner or later. Been burned before... :)

Comment: Okay, okay, I know.  But I don't like the "where population > 0" either, as it could exclude that country when you wanted to show it. Fixed it in a way that keeps those.

Answer (score 0):

To deal with the 0 population division by zero, I'd suggest using a [CASE statement](https://web.archive.org/web/20210728081626/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/102704-1.shtml)

```
SELECT
    Name,
    CASE IsNull(population,0)
        WHEN 0
            THEN 0
        ELSE
            THEN gdp/population
    END AS 'PerCapitaGDP'
FROM Countries
```

This will work on MS SQL Server, you may need to look up syntax for which DBMS you are using (for example, it looks like MySQL uses END CASE instead of just END)